Axios in context
I make a React client with SpringBoot backend and Keycloak auth server. I'd like store Bearer token in axios instance globally. The header is lost every request so I need configure it every http call. In App.tsx I coded this:
import './App.css'
import './scss/main.scss'
import './components/Header'
import Protected from './components/Protected'
import Navigation from './components/Nav'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Doctor from './components/Doctor'
import { AuthProvider } from "react-oidc-context";
import { WebStorageStateStore } from "oidc-client-ts";
import { AxiosContext } from "./components/AxiosContext.ts";
import axios from "axios";
import {useRef} from "react";

const oidcConfig = {
    authority: "https://myserver.hu:9443/realms/somerealm",
    client_id: "public-client",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.sessionStorage }),
    monitorSession: true,
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
};

function App() {

    const httpClient= useRef(axios.create({
    }))

    return (
      <AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}
                    onSigninCallback={(user) => {
                        console.log(`Signin callback called. user access token: ${user?.access_token}`)
                        httpClient.current.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user?.access_token}`;
                    }}
                    onRemoveUser={() => {
                    }}>
          <AxiosContext.Provider value={httpClient.current}>
              <Navigation />
              <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                  <Route path="/doctor" element={<Doctor />} />
                  <Route path="/protected" element={<Protected />} />
                </Routes>
              </BrowserRouter>
          </AxiosContext.Provider>
      </AuthProvider>

  )
}

export default App

Protected.tsx content like this:
import { useQuery } from "react-query"
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
import { hasAuthParams, useAuth } from "react-oidc-context";
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { AxiosContext } from "./AxiosContext";

type UserInfo = {
    name: string,
    sub: string,
    roles: string[],
    email: string,
}

const Protected = () => {

    const auth = useAuth();
    const [hasTriedSignin, setHasTriedSignin] = useState(false);
    const axiosCtx = useContext(AxiosContext)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!(hasAuthParams() || auth.isAuthenticated || auth.activeNavigator || auth.isLoading || hasTriedSignin)) {
            void auth.signinRedirect();
            setHasTriedSignin(true);
        }
    }, [auth, hasTriedSignin]);

    const fetchUserInfo = (): Promise<UserInfo> | null => {
        if (auth.user?.access_token) {
            axiosCtx.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${auth.user?.access_token}`;
        }
        return auth.isAuthenticated ? axiosCtx.get("/api/user/info", {
        }).then((res) => {
            return res.data
        }) : null

    }

    const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery({
        queryKey: ['repoData', auth.isAuthenticated],
        queryFn: fetchUserInfo
    })

    if (isLoading) return <b>Loading...</b>

    if (error) return (<div>An error has occurred: {JSON.stringify(error)}</div>)

    return (
        data ?
            <div>
                <h1>{data.name}</h1>
                <Button onClick={() => { alert(JSON.stringify(auth.user?.access_token)) }}
                    className="m-1 custom-btn-style"
                    label='Show Parsed Access token'
                    severity="warning" />

                <Button onClick={() => { auth.removeUser(); auth.signoutRedirect(); }}
                    className="m-1 custom-btn-style"
                    label='Logout'
                    severity="warning" />

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>UserId</strong></td><td>{data.sub}{' '}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>Roles</strong></td><td>{JSON.stringify(data.roles)}{' '}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>Email</strong></td><td>{data.email}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div> : <></>
    )
}

export default Protected

AxiosContext looks like this:
export const AxiosContext = createContext({} as AxiosInstance);

I'd like set bearer token once a time. How should I solve the problem?
Thanks for suggestions.
